# 1 platform with 2 different type of user accounts with different roles

Tags: customer-account

I will try to explain my problem, excuse me for my English but i'm Italian.

OK, my client want an e-commerce website with dual functionality.

1. Sell products to regular customers
2. Sell products to retailers

Simply put two different types of users

For example, the same product with different prices:

1. Costumer price: 10 $
2. Retail price: 5 $

Can i do it whit Magento? Is it preferable to use one platform or use two different platforms?

thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default Magento will do this right out of the box. It is called customer groups. All you will have to do is assign the customers that should be "retailers" to the retailers customer group in the backend.
[image]

When you are at a product, you simply add another tier for the customer group (shown in the picture):
[image]